# "Call to undefined function" error for global "curl_init" function because of Namespace

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I use something like this:

```
namespace Lorem ;

class Ipsum {
    function foo ($url) {
        $c = curl_init($url) ;
    }
}
```

But I got an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Lorem\curl_init()
```

This error occurs even I put `curl_init($url)` to the outside of class.

How can I stop it?

**Edit: I got CURL extension installed.**

Comment: `apt-get install php7.x-curl`

Comment: I use php v5.6.31, and have no right to update it...

Comment: `apt-get install php5-curl`

Comment: I got CURL extension installed.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: It shouldn't be required but try `$c = \curl_init($url)`

Comment: @Digerkam if you only just installed the curl extension, have you restarted your HTTP server (eg Apache)?

Answer (score -1):

Ohh this is because you are using curl_init inside a namespace; To solve it just use backslash before curl_init();

code:

```
$c = \curl_init($url);
```

Comment: Yeah but why is that required?? When a function name doesn't exist within the current namespace, PHP is supposed to fallback to the global namespace. You don't have to prepend a \ to \strpos(), \is_array() etc etc. Why is it required for \curl_init()??

Comment: The slash is not needed, the extension seems to be not installed. You can check by function_exists('curl_version') or extension_loaded('curl’). If it is installed and active, you should get true.